# Get list of resource mailboxes from Exchange online

Tags: azure, office365

I'm trying to get a list of all resource mailboxes (actually only rooms) that exists on my Exchange Online tenant. All my shoots have been made using EWS, but using GetRoomLists() do not work since room lists are not created by default.

I read on MSDN that EWS cannot be used to query for the information I need so I tried doing so by using Graph API to ask directly to Azure AD for all rooms in my tenant (That's the recommended method for on-premises infrastructures, using System.Directory namespace), but I'm unable to find a way to get that information.

I did my tries with C# and Obj-C (using SOAP), so I don't mind the language used to get the information if I can get that info.

Another point is that I cannot use any kind of federated AD.

Is there someone that have any ideas of how to perform that kind of queries?

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same thing. Did you get a chance to fetch the list?

Comment: Hi @AAhad but I'm afraid that there's no way to do that on O365. The only way that I found is creating a room list and put into all meeting rooms that you need. Querying Graph for this is not an option since this kind of information is not published through Graph.